# ¿Cómo guardar datos provenientes de un ciclo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Estoy en un gran problema, tengo una variable que cambia de valor mediante una operación dentro de un ciclo `for`, digamos `f`, necesito ir guardando cada uno de esos valores que toma `r` dentro de un array para luego graficar. como puedo lograr eso? es decir, al final obtener un array como: `resultados=[f0, f1, f2, ... ,fN]` pero crear una lista por ejemplo `R= [ ]` antes del ciclo y después usar `R.append()` no funciona.
Les dejo mi código por si puede ser de ayuda.

```
import numpy as np

n=2

po=0.25

p1 = 1 -po

prob = [po,p1]

while len(prob)<= pow(2,n-1):

    A = [z*po for z in prob]
    B = [z*p1 for z in prob]
    prob = A + B
print(prob)


N = np.arange(0,2**n,1)
C = np.arange(1,n+1,1)
Q = np.arange(-5,6,1)

L = [2**c for c in C]

for q in Q:

    P = []
    sF = []
    sA = []
    for k in N:
        P.append(prob[k]**q)
        for c in C:
            if len(P) == pow(2,c):
                M = P/sum(P)
                F = [m*np.log(m) for m in M]
                A = [m*np.log(p) for m,p in zip(M,P)]
                sF.append(sum(F))
                if len(sF)==len(L):
                    f = pol.polynomial.polyfit(np.log(L), sF, deg=1)
```

La parte importante es que `f` consta de 11 array de dos entradas, quiero seleccionar sólo `f[1]` y guardarlo en un nuevo array. Pero quiero los 11 generados y al final del ciclo solo me guarda el último calculado.

Comment: Sería bueno que dieras un poco más de contexto sobre el problema que intentas resolver para poder darte una mejor respuesta. Además te recomiendo de que nombres mejor tus variables para que sea más facil leer tu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.polynomial as pol

n=2

po=0.25

p1 = 1 -po

prob = [po,p1]

while len(prob)<= pow(2,n-1):
    A = [z*po for z in prob]
    B = [z*p1 for z in prob]
    prob = A + B

N = np.arange(0,2**n,1)
C = np.arange(1,n+1,1)
Q = np.arange(-5,6,1)

L = [2**c for c in C]

R = []
for q in Q:

    P = []
    sF = []
    sA = []
    for k in N:
        P.append(prob[k]**q)
        for c in C:
            if len(P) == pow(2,c):
                M = P/sum(P)
                F = [m*np.log(m) for m in M]
                A = [m*np.log(p) for m,p in zip(M,P)]
                sF.append(sum(F))
                if len(sF)==len(L):
                    f = pol.polynomial.polyfit(np.log(L), sF, deg=1)
                    R.append(f[1])
```

`R` te va a guardar el segundo elemento de `f` (que tiene 2 elementos).

Comment: Gracias! si funciona!